# How can I create a short cut to wrap selection sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to be able to select some content in sublime text, then press `cmd`+`ctrl`+`l` and then the selected content to be wrapped with an advanced version of markdown link. for example

```
[ $selection ](linkGoesHere "titleGoesHere")
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example? Do you want to use fields (tab to edit next field)?

Answer (score 0):

You can likely get this working by writing a [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) or [plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) to suit your needs.

You will be able to bind a plugin to your preferred keystroke, but snippets are triggered as you type in your file. Therefore a plugin is more likely to be your solution (since this requires some text to be written, selected, then the command executed), but if that ends up as a dead end, you might be able to use a snippet to accomplish the same task.